# Not able to load data into pig on EMR from S3 bucket (parquet file)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-pig, amazon-emr, parquet

I want to load the data from s3 bucket in Pig on EMR and my source file format is parquet:

Below command i have used:

```
A = LOAD 's3://test-1/icted/emp_db/emp_tb' 
USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader(header__change_seq:chararray,header__change_oper:chararray,header__change_mask:chararray,header__stream_position:chararray,header__operation:chararray,header__transaction_id:chararray,header__timestamp:chararray,policylangaccessind_afi:chararray,loadcommandid:double,previousgroupid:double,enddate:chararray,assignedbyuserid:double,dstcd_afi:chararray);
```

I am not able to load data getting below are the error:

```
      ERROR pig.PigServer: exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file test.pig, line 20, column 2>  mismatched input 'header__change_seq' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

You should be using the full class path on emr `org.apache.parquet.pig.ParquetLoader()`; no need to pass it a schema, the parquet reader will infer it for you.

Make sure you are using a version of the pig code that is compatible with the version of the parquet file (parquet tools can be used to find the version of parquet used)

Just try to use most recent version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-pig-bundle/1.10.0

```
REGISTER parquet-pig-bundle-1.10.0.jar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `''`

```
A = LOAD 's3://test-1/icted/emp_db/emp_tb' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader('header__change_seq:chararray,header__change_oper:chararray,header__change_mask:chararray,header__stream_position:chararray,header__operation:chararray,header__transaction_id:chararray,header__timestamp:chararray,policylangaccessind_afi:chararray,loadcommandid:double,previousgroupid:double,enddate:chararray,assignedbyuserid:double,dstcd_afi:chararray');
```

Or

Missing `as` after `ParquetLoader`

```
A = LOAD 's3://test-1/icted/emp_db/emp_tb' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader AS (header__change_seq:chararray,header__change_oper:chararray,header__change_mask:chararray,header__stream_position:chararray,header__operation:chararray,header__transaction_id:chararray,header__timestamp:chararray,policylangaccessind_afi:chararray,loadcommandid:double,previousgroupid:double,enddate:chararray,assignedbyuserid:double,dstcd_afi:chararray);
```

Comment: thanks for your response i am getting below error  for 1st options , errorMessage=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: schema sizes don't match:
message spark_schema {
  optional binary header__change_seq (UTF8);
  optional binary header__change_oper (UTF8);
  optional binary header__change_mask (UTF8);
  optional binary header__stream_position (UTF8);
  optional binary header__operation (UTF8);
  optional binary header__transaction_id (UTF8);
  optional int96 header__timestamp;
}

Comment: and for 2nd option ---->7153 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1200: can't convert optional int96 header__timestamp

Comment: i am very new to the EMR but your response can help me lot.